# Fill the data from previous date for each product till no change is seen

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has `date`,`product` and it's `price`. The table has entries only when there is price change for a particular product.

```
+------------+---------+-------+
|     dt     | product | price |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | A       |    10 |
| 2020-01-06 | A       |    12 |
| 2020-01-09 | A       |    14 |
| 2020-01-01 | B       |    12 |
| 2020-01-04 | B       |    10 |
| 2020-01-07 | B       |    13 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

For example price of product A was 10 from 2020-01-01 till 2020-01-05. It got changed to 12 on 2020-01-06 and again got changed to 14 on 2020-01-09.

I want to expand the above table and get all dates for each product.The expanded table should have updated prices from the date where price changes till the next date where price change is seen.

```
+------------+---------+-------+
|     dt     | product | price |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | A       | 10    |
| 2020-01-02 | A       | 10    |
| 2020-01-03 | A       | 10    |
| 2020-01-04 | A       | 10    |
| 2020-01-05 | A       | 10    |
| 2020-01-06 | A       | 12    |
| 2020-01-07 | A       | 12    |
| 2020-01-08 | A       | 12    |
| 2020-01-09 | A       | 14    |
| 2020-01-10 | A       | 14    |
| …..        | …       | …     |
| 2020-01-01 | B       | 12    |
| 2020-01-02 | B       | 12    |
| 2020-01-03 | B       | 12    |
| 2020-01-04 | B       | 10    |
| 2020-01-05 | B       | 10    |
| 2020-01-06 | B       | 10    |
| 2020-01-07 | B       | 13    |
| 2020-01-08 | B       | 13    |
| 2020-01-09 | B       | 13    |
| 2020-01-10 | B       | 13    |
| ….         | ….      | …     |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

My attempt to solve the question can be seen at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b53b/4). Any help will be really appreciated.

I tried it by below approach

```
SELECT date,product,price,
COUNT(product) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY dt) product_count,
COUNT(price) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY dt) price_count
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM table2 A
LEFT JOIN table1 B
ON A.date = B.dt) T
```

Then I wanted to use `FIRST_VALUE() OVER()` to get the previous value. But that doesnt seem to be helping

Comment: How do you know the price at 2020-01-10 if you only have records until 2020-01-09 ?? I mean, you should only expand results to 2020-01-09 (for each product)

Comment: As long as price is not changing. It will be carried forward as it is. The latest change is seen at 2020-01-09. So 2020-01-09 price will be carried forward

Comment: So it should display values until current date. You probably should include that function in your query

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to generate a table of prices for each product on each day, which can be done with a `CROSS JOIN` of `Table2` with the `DISTINCT` products from `Table1` and then `LEFT JOIN`ing `Table1` to get the prices. This can then be used with `OUTER APPLY` to generate the previous highest price for that product on that day, and we use `COALESCE` to use that as the price if the price for that date is `NULL`:

```
WITH daily_data AS (
  SELECT t2.date, p.product, t1.price
  FROM Table2 t2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT product 
    FROM Table1
  ) p
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.dt = t2.date AND t1.product = p.product
)
SELECT date, product,
       COALESCE(price, dd1.prev_price) AS price
FROM daily_data dd
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 price AS prev_price
  FROM daily_data dd2
  WHERE dd.date > dd2.date AND dd.product = dd2.product AND price IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY date DESC) dd1
ORDER BY product, date
```

Output:

```
date        product     price
2020-01-01  A           10
2020-01-02  A           10
2020-01-03  A           10
2020-01-04  A           10
2020-01-05  A           10
2020-01-06  A           12
2020-01-07  A           12
2020-01-08  A           12
2020-01-09  A           14
2020-01-10  A           14
2020-01-01  B           12
2020-01-02  B           12
2020-01-03  B           12
2020-01-04  B           10
2020-01-05  B           10
2020-01-06  B           10
2020-01-07  B           13
2020-01-08  B           13
2020-01-09  B           13
2020-01-10  B           13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7ef2601fce7b9d8884553a92bbdd2f7)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a tally table, then a recursive CTE is a perfectly reasonable approach:

```
with cte as (
      select product, price, dt,
             dateadd(day, -1, lead(dt, 1, '2020-01-11') over (partition by product order by dt)) as next_dt,
             1 as lev
      from table1
      union all
      select product, price, dateadd(day, 1, dt), next_dt, lev + 1
      from cte
      where dt < next_dt
     )
select product, dt, price
from cte
order by product, dt;
```

If you have the same price for more than 100 days, then add `option (maxrecursion 100)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5bce837401c296bf9998f39877e8dcc) is a db<>fiddle.